# javascript how can remove indexes inside array thats starts with certain letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, loops

```
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];
let index = 0;
let counter = 0;

while (index < friends.length) {
  index++;
  if (
    typeof friends[index] === "number" &&
    friends[index] == friends[index].startsWith("a".toUpperCase())
  ) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log(friends[index]);
}
```

what's wrong with my code i get a syntax error   this is the output i want
i want to remove the numbers and the names thats starts with letter a

Output
"1 => Sayed
"2 => Mahmoud

Comment: do you have `friends` as well? btw, why increasing index first (it usually cames last ...)?

Comment: Please provide an example `friends` array. A "snippet" is nice too.

Comment: As @NinaScholz said, What happens if you move `index++` to the end of the loop? You are starting with the second element of your list instead of the first one.

Comment: `typeof friends[index] === "number" && friends[index] == friends[index].startsWith("a".toUpperCase())` ?? You're checking if the `friends` elements BOTH are type number AND starts with uppercase "a" ?

Comment: Unless this is a coding challenge, you'd probably want to use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: i moved index++ to the last of the loop and it starts from the index 0 great but i still have the problem that syntax is error i want only the output from this array i can't use array.filter because its a challenge this is the array.      friends let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

*First*, as mentioned, `index++` first in the loop block increments `index` to `1`. So the loop skips the first element and starts with the second element, and tries to access a non-existent element on the final loop.

```
// the array:
["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"]

// the array indexes:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

// the indexes called by the loop:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

*Second*,

```
typeof friends[index] === "number" && friends[index] == friends[index].startsWith("a".toUpperCase())
```

...is an impossibility—always `false`. Do you mean:

```
typeof index === "number" && friends[index] == friends[index].startsWith("a".toUpperCase())
```

...and if so, why? If not, what? (EDIT: Question answered by question update—some elements are numbers.)

Furthermore, how is:

```
friends[index] == friends[index].startsWith("a".toUpperCase())
```

...a possiblity? `startsWith()` returns boolean true or false. "soft" equality `==` will equate negative nubmers and `0` to `false`, and any other number to `true`.

*Third*, there's nothing removing elements from the array.

*Fourth*, if the code did accomplish to remove elements from the `friends` array it would alter the `index`'ed location of the array elements, and the sequence flow would be corrupted.

Resolving these problems, and [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)'ing to a new array:

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];
let friends_noa = [];
let index = 0;
let counter = 0;

while (index < friends.length) {
  if (
    typeof friends[index] === "number" ||
    friends[index].startsWith("a".toUpperCase())
  ) {
    index++;
    continue;
  }
  friends_noa.push(friends[index]);
  console.log(friends[index]);
  index++;
}
console.log(friends_noa);
```

Also, if your challenge does not allow you to create a new array, use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];
let index = 0;
let counter = 0;

while (index < friends.length) {
  if (
    typeof friends[index] === "number" ||
    friends[index].startsWith("a".toUpperCase())
  ) {
    friends.splice(index, 1);
    continue;
  }
  console.log(friends[index]);
  index++;
}
console.log(friends);
```

However, it's simpler to use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)—this is what it's made for:

```js
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];

friends = friends.filter(function (name) {
  return (("number" !== typeof name) 
    && !name.startsWith("A"));
});

console.log(friends);
```

Comment: @MrAhmedAlhamed Please add that to the question so everyone can see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
let friends = ["Ahmed", "Sayed", "Ali", 1, 2, "Mahmoud", "Amany"];
let index = 0;
let counter = 0;

while (index < friends.length) {
  if (typeof friends[index] === "number" || friends[index].startsWith("A")) {
    index++;
    continue;
  } else {
    console.log(`${++counter} => ${friends[index]}`);
    index++;
  }
}
```

i found the solotion

Comment: Well done. So you know, it's okay to accept your own answer.